# Why this CSS cube 3d menu works fine in my apple but goes wrong in my pc?

Tags: css, menu, 3d

```
[please check my code][1]
```

I found no way to submit my code here, it is my first time,

I tried uploading a picture but a need some kind of reputation,

This is my homework, so please check the code of the link so see what is going on,

Thanks

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: http://www.cadremy.com/galeria2.htm

Comment: What seems to be the problem? On Stack Overflow you need to try to ask specific questions.

Comment: what browsers are you testing with?

Comment: it works in all browsers when looking from my apple, but when trying from PC it doesnt't work.

Comment: The 3d CSS menu looks with no 3d effect on pc, shows flat and and display both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses CSS properties such as `transform`, which need extra prefixes for each browser.
You probably use Chrome on your PC and Firefox on you Mac; in Chrome and Safari, you need to add `-webkit-` to certain properties:

This tool should help: http://prefixr.com/

Paste your CSS code in there, and it will fix all the prefixes.

Comment: You should mark the question as answered if all issues are resolved.

Comment: albertxing is working fine in all browsers and plataforms except for Internet Explorer on my PC

Comment: You have to have the `-ms-` prefix for IE9. On IE10, it should work fine without any prefixes (when in doubt, check caniuse.com: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).